# How often do you get a sunchoke that looks like ginger?

Tags: root-vegetables, potatoes, ginger, sunchoke

I was watching some videos on gardening, and was wondering how often a sunchoke will look like a ginger root system (a giant clump of one tuber).

Example:
[image: sunchoke like ginger]

Comment: For a reference see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZnx_1yQ6gg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of mine looked like that. Though some were a lot smaller, and I suspect these tiny ones are the ones you miss that let the patch grow again. On the other hand I did a second look a few days after removing all the sunchokes I could find, and still found several large ones!

I think it must be common.